# Laravel Query Item from table with selected relationships from another table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There are two tables which are related - Product and SalesForecast. I want to query products of a certain supplier with sales forecast from a period.

Relationships are established. My query is as follows:

```
$products = Product::where('supplier_id', $supplier)
    ->whereHas('stock_forecasts_fk', function ($query) use ($begin, $end) {
        $query->whereDate('date', '>', $begin);
        $query->whereDate('date', '<', $end);
    })
    ->get();
```

The relationship in the product model is as follows:

```
public function stock_forecasts_fk()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\StockForecast');
}
```

This query does not work 100%. I want all products of that supplier to come (whether they have forecast or not). If they have a forecast, I need forecasts for that period only. Otherwise, that product will have not, forecast. But All product needs to come. Can someone advise how to fix this query so the result is as follows:

All products of suppliers come with relevant forecasts of between begin and end dates. If there is no forecast, then the product can come with no forecast.

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly, you always want ALL products that belong to this supplier, but only load the relevant StockForecasts?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the document that I've read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

`whereHas` only includes Product which has stock_forecasts_fk, and discards Product which doesn't.

To select all product regardless it has stock_forecasts_fk, you should've use `with`.

```php
$products = Product::where('supplier_id', $supplier)
    ->with([
        'stock_forecasts_fk' => function ($query) use ($begin, $end) {
            $query->whereDate('date', '>', $begin);
            $query->whereDate('date', '<', $end);
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to query with eager loading the relationship. with `whereHas`, only matching related value products will be collected. use `with` closure to query in related table

```
$products = Product::with(['stock_forecasts_fk' => function($query) {
    $query->whereDate('date', '>', $begin)
        ->whereDate('date', '<', $end);
}])
->where('supplier_id', $supplier)
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with` and pass a closure with your conditions to it:

```
$products = Product::where('supplier_id', $supplier)
    ->with(['stock_forecasts_fk' => function ($query) use ($begin, $end) {
        $query->whereDate('date', '>', $begin)
            ->whereDate('date', '<', $end);
    }])
    ->get();
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

> **Constraining Eager Loads**
>
> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify
> additional query conditions for the eager loading query. Here's an
> example:

```
$users = App\Models\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}])->get();
```

> In this example, Eloquent will only eager load posts where the post's
> title column contains the word `first`.